# WCF:In Client side,Get Endpoint Ip Address

Tags: wcf

Is it Poosible to get the Ip Address of Client Side in WCF

In Service Side we can get Ip Address by using OperationContext.current.

The same way will i be able to get in Client Side

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

Sure - if you create your client, you can get its endpoint:

```
YourServiceClient client = new YourServiceClient();
string endpointAddress = client.Endpoint.Address.Uri.ToString();
```